# Square brackets in chemcompounds custom names

Tags: brackets, chemstyle

I would like to denote a molecular ion using the `chemcompounds` package. This would involve wrapping part of a `chemcompounds` descriptor in square brackets, like so:

`$[1]^{2+}$`

However, because the `chemcompounds` name argument is placed between square brackets, trying to do this causes an error.

How is it done?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{chemcompounds}
\declarecompound[J]{c1}
\declarecompound[J$^{+}$]{c1c}
%\declarecompound[[J]$^{+}$]{c1bc}

\begin{document}

This species is denoted \compound{c1}.

This molecular ion is denoted \compound{c1c}.

%This molecular ion breaks chemcompounds: \compound{c1bc}.

\end{document}
```

(I have commented out the lines that break compilation)

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, an extra pair of braces solves this kind of problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemcompounds}

\declarecompound[${[1]^{2+}}$]{label}

\begin{document}

\compound{label}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this was not the case, while you provide a proper MWE with `chemcompounds`, I would suggest you to use the [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{$[1]^{2+}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The extra braces fix the problem, thanks. I already use `mhchem` for formulae, but `chemcompounds` serves a different role, namely the consistent abbreviation of compounds.